# Processing mic input in iOS/React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, audio, avaudioengine

I have a React Native app that is doing doing some video calling (using the jisti package) and need to be able to manipulate the audio in real time. I assume that I need to "intercept" the audio signal from the mic and process that, and I assume that this would be in native code. I see the AVAudioX classes in iOS and Objective-C. I just don't see how to hook them into the flow. I've done a lot of React Native but almost no work on low level code on the device in the native language.

How do I do this? Is this the right approach or is there a better one?

Comment: Sadly SO isn’t a great platform for this type of question. I am familiar with the frustrations developers have when they suddenly have to do DSP, so here are some tips. 1. The tags in your question _only_ appear in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native+objective-c+audio This is a red flag as either you are breaking new ground (unlikely) or you might be taking the wrong approach (more likely). Check against react-native and audio. Better yet, sort by votes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native+audio

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out.

Comment: The question should more focus on if you try to hook up native audio buffer access of inputs or if you would try to go with web-API to catch audio. Two total different approaches. Depending on your use case it may be worth to consider of native audio api’s are better to use, where you would want to know how to access the result with react..

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that I need to intercept and modify the input audio on a native level. Unfortunately I have no experience with native iOS and haven't been able to figure it out. If I could at least hook in a passthrough function (just returns the input data unchanged for now), that would be a huge step in the right direction.

Comment: If you find any API on jitsi that delivers you the audioBuffers then you are good to go, still not meaning it can be done in real time. If you meant to intercept the buffer from your microphone to jitsi initiated call that may be possible.